# Delete files between two dates

Tags: files, rhel

I have a folder in which there are very old files. It contains files since 2009 and they are dump files with error log.

What I want to know is if it is possible to delete the files between let's say 2009 and 2011. Something like:

```
delete 'file_patern' between 2009-2011 and 2012-2014
```

I want to preserve for example 2010, 2015 and current year.

Machine is running on RedHat.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73268/how-to-move-the-files-based-on-year

Comment: Do the files' time stamps correspond to their date, or is the date embedded in their filenames somehow?

Answer (score 5):

To list all files that were modified between 2009 and 2011, use `find` with `-newermt`:

```
 find . -type f -newermt '01 jan 2009 00:00:00' -not -newermt '01 jan 2012 00:00:00' -ls
```

To remove:

```
find . -type f -newermt '01 jan 2009 00:00:00' -not -newermt '01 jan 2012 00:00:00' -delete
```